# How to share data globally among multiple view controllers

Tags: iphone, object, global, modalviewcontroller, viewcontroller

can anybody help me out please...

i have a huge object in a model. i made it as a single ton class and returning the object wn other calls.but the object is very big thats y the app is crasing. with out returning how to  share the data globally and when to alloc the object and where to dealloc the object. i dont need all the data in object in a viewcontroller ..i need specific data to a view controller from that object...

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of data are you talking about?

Comment: Be sure that the singleton is actually a singleton, otherwise you will have multiple instance of the very same model. Still, if the app is being terminated because of the memory footprint of the model, you can only avoid the problem by reducing the size of the model and/or load the necessary bits in memory. If it is an huge image, split it in multiple tiles. If you are instancing and stacking a lot of view controllers, be sure to implement a proper memory management (i.e. releasing retained views in viewDidUnload): it might not solve the issue, but it can alleviate it.

Comment: That's what I was getting at. If the model is too big, you need a different approach, like tiling or a database or...

Comment: @Joseph: the data is an array with objects.each object is a lesson contains audiofiles,images,webviews

Comment: To me that sounds like you should rethink your strategy. There is no real point in having a Singleton provide complex objects like that.

Comment: @Joseph:then please tell that whats the best way to share that data globally. i need those data among multipleviewcontrollers

Comment: Well the data is somewhere, right? The images, audiofiles etc. are either stored on the web, or locally in a database or the filesystem. You should get them only when you need them, inside the classes that are responsible for dealing with them. Sorry if that sounds trivial, but I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Actually i have an xml file with the data locally in documents folder.i parsed it and made an array of objects in a model.in the view controllers i am using that data

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't do that then. Parse it and get it when you need it. Parsing xml is pretty fast, so I don't think putting everything in an array will speed things up perceptibly.

Comment: then what is the reusability if we do parsing again and again for same data

Comment: Again, I don't know exactly what you are trying to do. But parsing all your available data and putting it in an array that crashes your application sounds like a suboptimal approach to me.

Comment: Thanks Joseph. i willtry and let u know

Comment: No problem. Think about how you can create classes that you can reuse rather than your parsed data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store a pointer to it in your app delegate and retrieve it using

```
BlahAppDelegate* delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
id bigObject = delegate.bigObject;
```

Since the app delegate will outlive the view controllers, you shouldn't have to worry about retain and release for it.

A singleton class should work similarly, as long as the singleton instance method (that retrieves the one created instance) calls retain on the instance when before it returns it.  When the view is dealloc-ed, make sure you call release on the instance.