# object sharing among view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was wondering how can I share a NSDictionary objects among several view controllers which basically are tabs in my application.

I tried using a protocol, like in Java, so that I can cast to the protocol and access the property. That doesn't seem to work.

Also I had a look at similar question at 
[How to share data globally among multiple view controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989491/how-to-share-data-globally-among-multiple-view-controllers)

But I observed that the appDelegate method is not safe and may lead to memory leak.

Similarly injection on class A into class B will create the same problem.

So can anyone suggest me any method which i should study or implement in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wants to share only Dictionary, why don't you go for class method using from helper class.

```
+(NSDictionary *)shareMethod
{
return dict;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use singleton class for sharing the data
Check this [Singleton class](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/)

`MyManger.h`

```
#import <foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyManager : NSObject {
NSMutableDictionary *_dict
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *dict;

 + (id)sharedManager;  
@end
```

`MyManger.m`

```
#import "MyManager.h"

static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;

 @implementation MyManager

 @synthesize dict = _dict;

#pragma mark Singleton Methods  

+ (id)sharedManager {
 @synchronized(self) {
    if(sharedMyManager == nil)
      sharedMyManager = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
 }
return sharedMyManager;
} 

- (id)init {
   if (self = [super init]) {
  dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
   }
 return self;
}
```

You can access your dictionary from everywhere like this

```
   [MyManager sharedManager].dict
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way out. Since I want a dictionary to be shared across, I declared a method in my protocol

```
- (void) setSingleHouse:(NSDictionary*) singleHouse;
```

In each of my controller I implemented the method in a appropriate manner. Hence I was able to share across them for now.

Also I figured out that I was casting in a wrong way earlier i.e (@protocol(protocol name)). Now changed it into NSObject .

Sorry for the fuss.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you not to use a property in your appDelegate instance. This pattern doesn't improve code reusability.

Basicly your shared NSDictionnary is your model. So, if you want your code to follow the MVC design parttern, you should create a class with a shared instance that would contain your NDDictionnary in a public property.

This is well explained in [this post](http://www.daveoncode.com/2011/12/19/fundamental-ios-design-patterns-sharedinstance-singleton-objective-c/)

This way, you will access your shared NSDictionnary this way
:

```
NSDictionary* sharedDictionnary = [MyModel sharedInstance].sharedDictionary;
```